# Accesing home network over Internet using my domain name with Dynamic DNS

Tags: networking, server, ssh, raspberrypi

I have a Raspberry PI with a Samba, FTP, DLNA and Webserver.

I wish to access it trough ssh and web with my domain like: `ssh username@my-domain.hu` and like: `home.my-domain.hu` the problem is I do not have static/constant IP adress, and I do not wish to buy one.

Is there a way to do it?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Use a Dynamic DNS, there are lots of providers. Then tell your router to redirect incoming traffic on the relevant ports to your raspberry pi. BUT: Unless you exactly know what you're doing (and if you're asking a question like this, you probably don't), I would advice not to do that at all. You open your network to the internet world and that is a very bad world. Rather use a VPN server. I wish good luck ;-) Anyways, this is not an Ubuntu question.

Comment: If your domain is routed through CloudFlare then you can have your Pi (or any other machine on the network) monitor your external IP address and update the DNS records via CloudFlare's API when there are changes.